# Trying to display entered values in same page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

Im trying to display entered values in same page,
When user enter the values in fields and submit, then the values should save database and should display in same jsp page.
I tried and the values are stored in database but not displaying on same page, but , it showing null values and then div disappears when submit action is performed 
And im using stored procedure in database

this is jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Stored Procedure</title>
<script>

function show(){
    document.stp.submit();
    document.getElementById("display").style.display="block";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="stp" action="STP" >

ID:<input type="text" name="ID"><br> 
Name:<input type="text" name="Name"><br>
Branch:<input type="text" name="Branch"><br>
MobileNo:<input type="tel" name="Mobile"><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="show()">
</form>
<div id="display" style="display:none">
Id:<%= request.getAttribute("id") %><br>
Name:<%= request.getAttribute("name") %><br>
Branch:<%= request.getAttribute("branch") %><br>
MobileNo:<%= request.getAttribute("mobile") %><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is servlet code:

```
package task;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/STP")
public class STP extends HttpServlet {
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));
        System.out.println(ID);
        String Name = request.getParameter("Name");
        String Branch = request.getParameter("Branch");
        long Mobile =Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("Mobile"));
        try {

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas", "root", "root");

            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call Procedure3(?,?,?,?)}");
            cs.setInt(1, ID);
            cs.setString(2, Name);
            cs.setString(3,Branch);
            cs.setLong(4,Mobile);

            cs.execute();
            int id=cs.getInt(1);
            String name=cs.getString(2);
            String branch=cs.getString(3);
            long mobile=cs.getLong(4);
            request.setAttribute("id",id);
            request.setAttribute("name",name);
            request.setAttribute("branch",branch);
            request.setAttribute("mobile",mobile);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("StoredProcedure.jsp").forward(request, response); 
        System.out.println(id);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to forward the request and response by using RequestDispatcher also your using DOM on body load display:none. it will not display after loading, because whole page refreshed here.

Remove the function bodyLoad() instead of this, write in-line style on div. For eg:-

```
<div id="display" style="display:none;">//your dom goes here </div>
```

Comment: yes i did but, it showing null values and then div disappears when submit action is performed

Comment: @vicky you are calling `bodyload` function in onload event. You should check request parameters are not null in bodyload function itself and call show() function.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try below code it will run perfectly in your system.

**JSP code:-**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="task.STP"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Stored Procedure</title>
<script>
    function bodyload() {
        document.getElementById("display").style.display = "none";
    }
    function show() {
        document.stp.submit();
        document.getElementById("display").style.display = "block";

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="stp" action="STP">

        ID:<input type="text" name="ID"><br> Name:<input
            type="text" name="Name"><br> Branch:<input type="text"
            name="Branch"><br> MobileNo:<input type="tel"
            name="Mobile"><br> <input type="button" value="Submit"
            onclick="show()">
    </form>
    <%
        if (STP.display) {
    %>

    <div id="display">
        Id:<%=request.getAttribute("id")%><br> Name:<%=request.getAttribute("name")%><br>
        Branch:<%=request.getAttribute("branch")%><br> MobileNo:<%=request.getAttribute("mobile")%><br>
    </div>
    <%
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

**servlet code:-**

```
package task;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/STP")
public class STP extends HttpServlet {
    public static boolean display = false;
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));
        System.out.println(ID);
        String Name = request.getParameter("Name");
        String Branch = request.getParameter("Branch");
        long Mobile = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("Mobile"));
        try {

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas", "root", "root");

            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call Procedure3(?,?,?,?)}");
            cs.setInt(1, ID);
            cs.setString(2, Name);
            cs.setString(3, Branch);
            cs.setLong(4, Mobile);

            cs.execute();
            int id = cs.getInt(1);
            String name = cs.getString(2);
            String branch = cs.getString(3);
            long mobile = cs.getLong(4);
            request.setAttribute("id", ID);
            request.setAttribute("name", Name);
            request.setAttribute("branch", Branch);
            request.setAttribute("mobile", Mobile);
            display = true;
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            System.out.println(ID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, please try and let us share experience.

Comment: This is not a good design pattern to follow. Please try to learn and implement an MVC design pattern.

Comment: Hi sumesh TG., I'm trying to give solution for asking questioner. Thanks for the information for design implementation.